# Javascript Form Validation for multiple field types

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Apologies if this is any easy one im not big on the Javascript knowledge.

Background of the current problem/project

Simple HTML form with Text fields, Check boxes and radio buttons

Submit  the form will pass all fields into a main validation function which will step through each field and in turn pass these fields to the relevent validation function (empty validation, email check etc)

The main form Validation function is as follows (i have changed the names of certain things as required by the company i am building for)

```
function formvalidation(thisform)
{
with (thisform)
{
if (emptyvalidation(CompName,"Please Enter your name")==false) {CompName.focus(); return false;};
if (emailvalidation(CompEmail,"Please provide a valid Company Email Address")==false)   {CompEmail.focus(); return false;};
if (emptyvalidation(CompEmail,"Please provide a valid Company Email Address")==false)     {CompEmail.focus(); return false;};
if (emptyvalidation(Company,"Please Enter Your Company Name")==false) {Company.focus(); return false;};
if (emptyvalidation(CompWebsite,"Please Enter Your Company's Website")==false) {CompWebsite.focus(); return false;};
if (emptyvalidation(CustName,"Please Enter an Agents name")==false) {CustName.focus(); return false;};
if (emailvalidation(CustEmail,"Please provide a valid Email Address")==false) {CustEmail.focus(); return false;};
if (emptyvalidation(CustEmail,"Please provide a valid Email Address")==false) {CustEmail.focus(); return false;};
if (emptyvalidation(CustCompany,"Please Enter The Agency Name")==false) {CustCompany.focus(); return false;};
if (emptyvalidation(CustWebsite,"Please Enter The Agents Website")==false) {CustWebsite.focus(); return false;};
if (checkCheckBoxes(use,"Please Select At Least One Option For Intended Data Use")==false) {use.focus(); return false;};
if (checkCheckBoxes(database,"Please Select An Option For Database Usage")==false) {database.focus(); return false;};
}
}
```

Ok So all other functions work correctly, the empty validation is as follows:

```
function emptyvalidation(entered, alertbox)
{
with (entered)
{
if (value==null || value=="")
{if (alertbox!="") {alert(alertbox);} return false;}
else {return true;}
}
}
```

The problem i currently have is getting check boxes to be validated, the function i have to validated if at least one check box is filled in is as follows

```
function checkCheckBoxes(entered, alertbox) {
    if (
    entered.checked == false) 
    {
        return false;
    } else {    
        return true;
    }
}
```

Basically we have 2 sets of check boxes 1 group called use one called database

Each group needs at least one option selected to be validated.

so i am trying to pass the info over into the above function in the same way it is passed into the other functions

Currently the validation is basically being completely ignored for these two fields.

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try `entered.value` for the first one? `with` doesn't always work as expected, in my experience.

Quote from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Description) on Mozilla's Developer Network:

> Using `with` is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode.

For the checkbox, try dropping the `== false` comparison and just use `if(entered.checked)`

Comment: Thanks for the above, i am reluctant at this stage to change the With as this function is working correctly (just included as an example of one function working compared to the other that isn't), i have removed the ==false but this has not helped at all, any other suggestions?